# SSRS - Using COUNTDISTINCT based off boolean field result

Tags: reporting-services, count, expression

I have a boolean field of RetailLocation and based on whether this field is True i want to Count the distinct values from the CustomerLocation field that holds store ID's. The total result is to get an average value of calls per location.
So far i have the below but i am getting this error:
Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Field' and 'Boolean'.

```
=COUNTDISTINCT(IIF(Fields!RetailLocation.Value=true,
Fields!CustomerLocation.Value, Nothing),"MonthlyIncidentReviewRetailLogged")/
SUM(IIF(Fields!RetailLocation.Value=true,1, 0),"MonthlyIncidentReviewRetailLogged")
```

Comment: Kicking myself here, noticed as i posted i was missing the Value off RetailLocation.

Comment: If you haven't solved the issue, try changing  `Fields!RetailLocation.Value=true` for `Fields!RetailLocation.Value=1`.